# Turn off VisualAssist for *.cl, *.cu and *.cuh

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, opencl, visual-assist

How can I define which filetypes are affected by VisualAssist in Visual Studio 2010?

For example, I don't like how this tool works with openCL and cuda files, therefore I would like to turn off it for these file types (oherwise it highlights 1000 errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Assist does not underline errors in C/C++ files in VS2010 - that is done by the default intellisense.  You can disable underlining but not on a per-file extension basis; it is all or nothing.  See `Tools | Options | Text Editor | C/C++ | Advanced | Disable Squiggles`.

Comment: It works, but it isn't good solution. i prefer to have some underlined line.

i think the topic is closed. thx all.

Answer (score 3):

Try-

VAssistX\Projects\File Handling\Extentions to ignore.

Comment: This is the solution I have looked for. 
But have to find out, how to set up the VS2010 for normal working with OCL/CUDA files.

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Visual Assist works based on which language editor is being used (i.e. get C++ assistance for file extensions defined as being C++ files), you can map file extensions to editors is Tools | Options | Text Editor | File Extensions.

On the other hand if Visual Assist hard codes the file extensions you will need to get in contact with the vendor.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the VS 2010. If I turn off the visual assist, then VS underlines keywords like "float4" nevertheless,  though it is highlighted as key word (I habe added all cuda/opencl stuff in usertype in Common7\IDE\ folder).