# The right way to setup VisualStudio 2010 for OpenCL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencl

what is the right way to setup VisualStuio 2010 for working with *.cl files? I have added *.cl under Tool/Text editor/File extensions and copied usertype.dat into the common7/ide folder, but VS underlines keywords like float4 or cross.

Is it necessary to add some key in registry or can somebody propose a tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

PS
i have already asked similar question [old one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032145/turn-off-visualassit-for-cl-cu-and-cuh), but now i am looking explicit for a solution with vs2010. It is not bad, but really nerves and deflects me from programming tasks.

Answer (score 1):

A hint for syntax color, as pointed in [this article](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/), the usertype.dat should be placed in the same directory that devenv.exe (c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE for default intall.). In my case, VS2010 was installed on D drive and placing it with devenv.exe do the trick.

But i still have error marks in my .cl files for opencl keywords like __kernel (compiling is OK)