# How to configure OpenCL in visual studio2010 for nvidia's gpu on windows?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I am using NVIDIA's GeForce GTX 480 GPU on Wwindows 7 operating system on my ASUS laptop. I have already configured Visual Studio 2010 for CUDA 4.2. How to configure OpenCL for nvidia's gpu on visual studio 2010?? Have tries every possible way.

Is it possible by any way to use 'CUDA toolkit (CUDA 4.2)' and 'nvidia's gpu computing sdk' to program OpenCL? If yes then How? If no then what is other way?

Comment: I have tried almost all forums but still I am not able to start programming on my device. I am in urgent need of OpenCL installation on my nvidia's device.Somebody please give me step-wise answer for this question.

Comment: This question is overly broad. If it didn't have an open bounty it would probably be closed.  Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You should be able to use Visual Studio 2010 to program for OpenCL.  It should simply be a case of making sure that you have the right include directories and libraries setup.

Take a look at [this site](http://www.guineacode.com/2010/linking-and-compiling-opencl/) from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076485/the-right-way-to-setup-visualstudio-2010-for-opencl) on how to setup your VS2010 solution for OpenCL.

Comment: Most important thing is I have not installed any toolkit or sdk other than CUDA 4.2 and gpcomputing_sdk (from nvidia). Is that enough for OpenCL programming? Because when we install this toolkit and sdk it also installs libraries for OpenCL. 
I have included all the directories and also setup libraries. But still it is not working.

Comment: Can you provide a description of the failure. Is it a build error or a runtime error? Have you installed the CUDA 4.2 or newer driver?

Comment: Yes Greg..I have installed 306.97 latest nvidia's driver along with cuda4.2. When we configure cuda with vusual studio, we select 'BuildCustomization' by right click on our project. Then we select cuda4.2.targets. And then we right click on .cu file to select 'CUDA C/C++ Compiler'. But in  case of opencl should we do the same? Or the .cl files get compiled by any other compiler than nvcc??

Comment: I am getting errors like undefined symbols for every opencl keyword I am using. And  use nvcc compiler for my .cl or .cpp (by selecting C/C++ Compiler) then it gives error like nvcc does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The updated SDK can be found at:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
(various platforms, including windows 8)